# Bluetooth blood pressure device connectivity

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

i have a blood pressure device which is a blue tooth supported device. before buying i asked the seller to provide the protocol etc so i can use it in my android application. I am very new to both android and bluetooth connectivity. Any how i have searched around, and in my app i can see the paired devices and the one available devices, in available devices when i search for bluetooth devices i can see the BP monitor along with the mac address which i got from the device.xxx

now i dont exactly know two things which is really confusing to me, first is the RS 232 as shown below and second is the uuid provided, however i am also confused in sending uuid coz its 16bit and android supports 128 bits.

```
1. RS232 Transmit agreement [9600 baud rate] [none party][ 8 bit data][1 bit stop]

BLE uuid: 
Receive: service uuid:0xFFF0, characteristic UUID:0xFFF1

Send: service uuid:0xFFF0, characteristic UUID:0xFFF2
```

i assume it has something to get connected, however when i try to pair with the device from the android bluetooth sectoin, it prompt that cannot pair because of pin or pass etc. However they also ask me to install one application which i tested once and it can remotely activate the machine for measurement.

can any one guide me in the proper direction, i will be really thankful. Full instructions are provided below

[instruction set provided by vendor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfg8r.png)

Comment: You don't need to send GUID. Pair the device outside app. Then in your app, declare BluetoothAdapter, so getBondedDevices() should list  your device (Check device name to identify it). Now connect to device and follow the instruction set. Then, when it works OK, you can incorporate discovery and pairing in your app. Enjoy! :)

Comment: actually as i said, when i try to pair the device manually. It gives error of pin or passkey. I can not add it into the bonded devices unless i succesfully pair it first. also the UUID i have is in 0xFFF0 format? how to use that